# Ballerina debugging in IntelliJ Idea haults with "Collecting data.." message

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, wso2, ballerina

I am debugging my ballerina project in Intellij Idea. Ballerina version : 1.2.0 IntelliJ Idea Ballerina plugin version: 1.2.0.
Sometimes when I am debugging, once hit a breakpoint I see the message "Collecting data.." in the variables section in "Debugger" tool window. So I cannot see veriables or their values. Please note that this is intermittent, but happens so often. Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong which causes this issue?

[image: de]

Comment: I'd suggest submitting this issue to https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a debugger issue when fetching visible variables for a given stack frame in some contexts. It would be great if you can create an issue in [here](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues) including the source information which you are trying to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will open a git issue